# Loading only specific data from Firestore using StreamBuilder in Flutter/Dart

Tags: asynchronous, stream, dart, flutter

I am trying to load data from Firestore using StreamBuilder.
In my collection called `'connect'` there are may documents.
But I want to load only specific documents.

`'connections'` is a List that contains some keys in `'connect'` collection.
`'hello'` is a QuerySnapshot List that contains some documents in `'collection'` collection.

For example, if my DB contains documents with `documentID` of followings:

```
-LK5SAToCPhI1Zp5W_bL
-LK5Ypv0HeDCwcN4K41M
-LK5j-OGtNjMpgklUB4B
-LK5mOih9wuz5ZSebXMn
```

a list `'connections'` contains only a portion such as:

```
-LK5SAToCPhI1Zp5W_bL
-LK5Ypv0HeDCwcN4K41M
```

In a StreamBuilder I want to load only documents that have same name in connections. How can I load only specific documents?

Please Help me!

```
Firestore.instance.collection('connect')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((docSnap) {
  for (DocumentSnapshot docs in docSnap.documents) {
    if (connections.isNotEmpty) {
      for (String keys in connections) {
        if (docs.documentID.toString() == keys) {
          hello.add(docs);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Invitation!",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('connect').snapshots(),
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading ... ");
                  final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;

                  return ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      itemCount: messageCount,
                      itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                        final DocumentSnapshot document =
                        snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        if (document.documentID ==
                            hello[index].documentID) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Hello $messageCount")
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[Text("Wrong")],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      });
                },
              ),
            ),
            _buildLayout(),
          ],
        )));
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?